# Getting a lot of warning/log messages with Firebase for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I just added FireBase to my project. It works just fine but there's something that I haven't been able to figure out. When I run the app, it prints a lot of different messages. Is this an expected behavior?

[image]

If so, is there a way to stop/resume these logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the logging Xcode 8 has turned on by default.

You can turn it off by adding the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` environment variable to your scheme and setting it to `disable`.

[image]